# Change encoding of adf rich faces' fileDownloadActionListener

Tags: java, download, oracle-adf, weblogic11g

I am using *fileDownloadActionListener* as follows:

```
<af:fileDownloadActionListener contentType="text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15"
     filename="#{row.FileName}.txt"
     method="#{backingBeanScope.backing_pages_general_files_download.downloadFile}"/>
```

The download works fine.

I have the application deployed on weblogic:

1. Locally on Windows
2. Remotely on Linux

When I download the file from Windows deployment and open by notepad it shows encoding *ANSI*
When I download the file from Linux deployment and open by notepad it shows *UTF-8*

But I need the encoding of the dowmloaded file to be  *ISO-8859-15*.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in the following way:

1. I accessed the *file_to_read_from* with `UTF-8` format
2. I changed the contents to `ISO-8859-15`
3. I fetched the *bytes_to_write* and converted to `ISO-8859-15`
4. I put both to an byte array with `ISO-8859-15` format
5. Changed the `jspx` that contains the view to contents of `ISO-8859-15`